# Panel estimation coefficient

Tags: econometrics

I'm running both a panel analysis (the first I ever run, to be fair) and a time series analysis over a period of 50 years for twelve countries. In my estimation, one variable has a positive coefficient speaking at a time series level but has a negative coefficient. That variable I'm speaking about is the net return on net capital stock, which I used to explain the long term interest rates. So, my question is: is it normal that coefficient in panel analysis differs from the ones in the time series? And if so, what economic meaning does provide a negative correlation between long term rates and return on capital? Shouldn't be the opposite (i.e.: the higher the capital productivity, the higher the long term rates)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add country fixed effects.

Comment: In reality no, I run a simple GLS regression. But thank you!